# C# List remove from end, really O(n)?

Tags: c#, big-o

I've read a couple of articles stating that List.RemoveAt() is in O(n) time.

If I do something like:

```
var myList = new List<int>();

/* Add many ints to the list here. */

// Remove item at end of list:
myList.RemoveAt(myList.Count - 1); // Does this line run in O(n) time?
```

Removing from the end of the list should be O(1), as it just needs to decrement the list count.

Do I need to write my own class to have this behavior, or does removing the item at the end of a C# list already perform in O(1) time?

Comment: I'm aware that I could profile this and see, or use .NET reflector. The point of creating this question, is to create a searchable result for what I think is an important question. I failed to find an answer to this in my own searching.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In general `List<T>::RemoveAt` is O(N) because of the need to shift elements after the index up a slot in the array.  But for the specific case of removing from the end of the list no shifting is needed and it is consequently O(1)

Comment: Would it be the case that it is O(N) but `N` here is `list.Count - indexRemoved`?

Comment: Where did you read this?  Their docs would suggest otherwise, it appears the procedure is O(n) no matter what - aka, they aren't making a special case ..

Comment: @KevinDepue. It's not really a special case they're making, it's a special case in itself. Similar to iterating through a list, which is always O(N), but when the list only has 1 element it's also O(1) because N is 1 in this case. There's no reason to treat it as special case, but it remains a special case anyways.

Comment: @Jared - Does navigating to `arr[0]` is also o(1) ?  what about `arr[arr.length-1]` ?

Comment: For more information see [MS' reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,3d46113cc199059a,references) (@JaredPar and @Blorgbeard are spot on)

Answer (score 7):

Removing last item will actually be `O(1)` operation since only in this case `List` doesn't shift next items in array. Here is a code from Reflector:

```
this._size--;
if (index < this._size) // this statement is false if index equals last index in List
{
    Array.Copy(this._items, index + 1, this._items, index, this._size - index);
}
this._items[this._size] = default(T);
```

Comment: `Array.Copy` is just copying data, not allocating it.

Answer (score 3):

This should give you an idea

```
    public void RemoveAt(int index) {
        if ((uint)index >= (uint)_size) { 
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(); 
        }
        _size--; 
        if (index < _size) {
            Array.Copy(_items, index + 1, _items, index, _size - index);
        }
        _items[_size] = default(T); 
        _version++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When speaking asymptotically, O(N) is the worst case time complexity of the method itself, where N is the count. It cannot perform worse than that.

Practically, it would be in the order of O(N-I) (ignoring constant time overhead), where I is the index. This is deducible since all the items beyond the given index I needs to be shifted to position preceding them respectively in a List.

To see this intuitively, if N is 100 and index is 99 (last element), then there are no elements that need to be 'shifted' just the last element is deleted (or simply the count is decreased without changing the size of data structure).

Similarly, when N is 100, and index is 0 (first element), 99 shifts have to be made.

Run the following code and see for yourself:

```
int size = 1000000;
var list1 = new List<int>();
var list2 = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    list1.Add(i);
    list2.Add(i);
}

var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    list1.RemoveAt(size-1);
    list1.Add(0);
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    list2.RemoveAt(0);
    list2.Add(0);
}
sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Answer (score -3):

It seems to me that if this was actually relevant to your application, you could have measured it in less time than it took to ask the question. And now you have at least two contradictory answers, so you'll have to test it anyway.

The point I'm trying to make is that unless the MSDN docs say that removeAt is O(1) for items at the end of the list, you couldn't really count on it working that way, and it might change in any given .NET update. For that matter, the behavior could be different for different types, for all you know.

If List is the "natural" data structure to use, then use it. If removing items from the List ends up being a hot spot n your profiling, then maybe it's time to implement your own class.

Comment: If you had bothered to read the comment that I added to the question, you'd see that I addressed the issue of profiling or using reflector.

As for your second point about the properties of the List class changing in future revisions, I think that it's a valid point, but I also think that it's still reasonable to ask the question about the current state of affairs. Especially since it's not likely to see a change for a long time. After all, the programming industry changes relatively quickly, most implementation specific questions are only relevant for some limited amount of time.

Comment: If removing from end is O(1) today there is 99.999999% chance it will remain this way. I wouldn't suggest that he starts implementing his own data structures in the very very unlikely odds that this would change. About the "measure it yourself" part, it's not true that it would've been faster. Trusted people from SO like JaredPar can give a good answer in a matter of minutes or even seconds ;-)